# React Native Android debug build is using the prebuilt bundle instead of connecting to Metro

Tags: react-native

When I try to run my application on android using `react-native run-android` the app is not connecting to the Metro server but is using the bundle file in `android/app/src/main/assets` instead.

When I delete the bundle file I get two error screens that tell me that a bundle file could not be found and that a connection to the Metro server could not be made:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

This happens on both my physical device and a local emulator, but on iOS devices everything works as expected. I'm pretty clueless what might be causing this. I've also tried deleting all the build output and node_modules without any result.

Comment: I have no idea but did you try `rm -rf node_modules/ && rm package-lock.json && npm cache clean --force && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache` ?

Comment: Gave it a try, but still walking into the same issue, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of googling I found out what the issue was...
Some time ago the android API level was updated to level 28, and since API level 28 you need to specify if you want to use HTTP.

Metro uses HTTP for bundling so that's why it wasn't working.

I solved it by adding this line in the `application` part of `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```